# Linq Include method not showing up in viewmodel

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, mvvm, ria

I have a Silverlight app using mvvm with ria services.  I have a textbox on the view that the user puts in a Job Number and clicks find.  This find button is using the ICommand in xaml to go here..

```
public ICommand FindJob
{
    get
    {
        return new DelegateCommand(BeginFindJob, (o) => true);
    }
}

public void BeginFindJob(object o)
{
    if (!IsDesignTime)
    {
        IsLoading = true;
        string jobnum = o.ToString();
        OnPropertyChanged("IsLoading");
        LoadOperation<Job> loadOp = _context.Load<Job>(_context.GetJobsByJobNumQuery(jobnum));
        loadOp.Completed += new EventHandler(loadOp_Completed);
    }
}
```

It uses the GetJobsByJobNumQuery in my ria service like so..

```
public IQueryable<Job> GetJobsByJobNum(string JobNum)
{
    var query = ((from j in this.ObjectContext.Jobs
                  where j.JobNumber == JobNum
                  select j) as ObjectQuery<Job>).Include("JobHeadings").Include("JobContracts").Include("JobTags").Include("JobMarket"); 
    return query;
}
```

Im wanting it to return all the information about the job, so i wrote the query above to include all those relationships. Putting a breakpoint on the linq query and looking at the results, it has exactly what I wont. All the fields, JobHeadings and Contracts are working and bringing back all the bindings to that job. So now I bring that query back in my viewmodel and populate the fields, like so..

```
void loadOp_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        LoadOperation<Job> loadOp = sender as LoadOperation<Job>;
        if (!loadOp.HasError)
        {
            _job = loadOp.Entities.FirstOrDefault<Job>();

            base.IsLoading = false;
            base.ProgressBarVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            base.OnPropertyChanged("IsLoading");
            base.OnPropertyChanged("ProgressBarVisibility");
            base.OnPropertyChanged("CurrentJob");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

My problem is, that no relationship data is coming back.  All the basic Job info is coming back from the Job table in my db, but none of the info from the related tables is coming back in my viewmodel. Putting a bp in and looking at _job, which should contain everything, all the relationship tables JobHeading/JobContract say 'Enumeration yielded no results.'

So how is it not making its way back through to the viewmodel?  What can i do to get the full query results put into the view/viewmodel so I can make changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem with the metadata service not picking up my latest table associations.  After i went through that mess of regenerating the metadata, it was a simple matter of including and associating the correct keys.  Thank you Quinton Bernhardt for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

Should the Includes not be higher up on the ObjectSet?  like this:

```
public IQueryable<Job> GetJobsByJobNum(string JobNum)
    {
        var query = ((from j in this.ObjectContext.Jobs.Include("JobHeadings").Include("JobContracts").Include("JobTags").Include("JobMarket")
                      where j.JobNumber == JobNum
                      select j) as ObjectQuery<Job>); 
        return query;
    }
```

Comment: I have tried that, it works both ways in the query, but neither returns results to the viewmodel

Comment: Have you tried make the ria service perform the round trip to the db before returning the values with a .AsEnumerable() or .ToList() instead of an ObjectSet?  If i understand the code correctly the roundtrip to the Db will be attempted when the view calls FirstOrDefault() - perhaps the ria service should be doing that

Comment: No i havent tried that, but doing some more research, I found out I dont have any [Include][Association] in my metadata service. Could this be a major cause?